# Clipping/ Zooming in on shapefile using R

Tags: r, clip, zoom

I'm working on a shapefile of all the villages of Portugal from [this link](https://dados.gov.pt/s/resources/freguesias-de-portugal/20181112-195834/cont-aad-caop2017.zip).

I've uploaded it to ***R***:

```
#read in shapefile of portugal
portugal = readOGR(dsn = "./communities", layer = "Cont_AAD_CAOP2017", verbose=FALSE)
```

And I've got the coordinate reference system information

```
# get coordinate reference system information
st_crs(portugal)

Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: ETRS89 / Portugal TM06 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / Portugal TM06",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["Portugual TM06",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",39.6682583333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-8.13310833333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Topographic mapping (medium scale)."],
        AREA["Portugal - mainland - onshore."],
        BBOX[36.95,-9.56,42.16,-6.19]],
    ID["EPSG",3763]]
```

I now want to create a second shapefile using only a region of Portugal, as delimited by some coordinates, namely

```
W 8°46'00"-- W 7°40'00" / N 41°08'00" -- N 40°39'00"
```

How can I do this?

Once again, I'm using ***R***

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, first the level 1 administrative boundaries of PRT are downloaded (the provided link did not work) and converted to a `sf` object; then we convert the character coordinates to dms (degree-minute-second) and to decimal degrees with `as.numeric`. A polygon is built using those coordinates and afterwards the boundaries object is clipped (intersected) with the bbox polygon:

`sf` is the modern geospatial library for vector data in R, compatible with the pipe `%>%` operator; furthermore, it reads vector data way faster than `readOGR` with `read_sf`

```r
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

prt = raster::getData(name = "GADM", country = "PRT", level = 1) %>% st_as_sfc()
coords = c("-8°46'00\"",
"-7°40'00\"",
"41°08'00\"",
"40°39'00\"")
coords = char2dms(coords, chd = "°") %>%
 as.numeric()

bb_poly = st_bbox(c(xmin = coords[1], xmax = coords[2], ymin = coords[3], ymax = coords[4])) %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% st_set_crs(4326)


st_intersection(prt, bb_poly) %>% plot()
```

[image]